# Netflix Ribbon and Polling for Server List

Tags: load-balancing, hystrix, netflix, netflix-ribbon

I'm currently trying out the Netflix Ribbon library and I'm trying to dynamically update a list of available endpoints to load balance.

I've successfully created a `httpResourceGroup` that uses a configuration based server list, e.g.:

```
httpResourceGroup = Ribbon.createHttpResourceGroup("searchServiceClient",
                    ClientOptions.create()
                            .withMaxAutoRetriesNextServer(3)
                            .withLoadBalancerEnabled(true)
                            .withConfigurationBasedServerList(serverList))
```

However, I'd like to be able to use a `DynamicServerList` in the `httpResourceGroup`.  I've managed to build a load balancer as follows:

```
LoadBalancerBuilder.<Server>newBuilder()
                   .withDynamicServerList(servicesList)
                   .buildDynamicServerListLoadBalancer();
```

but I can't find a way to swap out the load balancer configured by the `httpResourceGroup` `ClientOptions`.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to not specify `withConfigurationBasedServerList()` when constructing an `HttpResourceGroup` since this I believe this is meant for a fixed list though I am not sure. There are many ways to initialize a dynamic load balancer (typically you would never swap it out, but reuse the same load balancer and swap out new `Server`s as they become available or go away. The most straightforward way to do this might be via Archaius-based configuration.

**Option 1**

Create a `config.properties` file on the classpath containing the following

```
ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName=com.example.MyServerList
ribbon.NFLoadBalancerRuleClassName=com.netflix.loadbalancer.RoundRobinRule
```

**Option 2**

```
    System.setProperty("ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName", "com.example.MyServerList");
    System.setProperty("ribbon.NFLoadBalancerRuleClassName", "com.netflix.loadbalancer.RoundRobinRule");
```

**Create a ServerList implementation**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.netflix.loadbalancer.Server;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.ServerList;


public class MyServerList implements ServerList<Server> {

    @Override
    public final List<Server> getUpdatedListOfServers() {
        // TODO do some fancy stuff here
        return Arrays.asList(new Server("1.2.3.4", 8888), new Server("5.6.7.8", 9999));
    }

    @Override
    public final List<Server> getInitialListOfServers() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Server("1.2.3.4", 8888), new Server("5.6.7.8", 9999));
    }    
}
```

**Run the code**

```
HttpResourceGroup httpResourceGroup = Ribbon.createHttpResourceGroup("searchServiceClient",
                        ClientOptions.create()
                                .withMaxAutoRetriesNextServer(3);
    HttpRequestTemplate<ByteBuf> recommendationsByUserIdTemplate = httpResourceGroup.newTemplateBuilder("recommendationsByUserId", ByteBuf.class)
                .withMethod("GET")
                .withUriTemplate("/users/{userId}/recommendations")
                .withFallbackProvider(new RecommendationServiceFallbackHandler())
                .withResponseValidator(new RecommendationServiceResponseValidator())
                .build();
    Observable<ByteBuf> result = recommendationsByUserIdTemplate.requestBuilder()
                            .withRequestProperty("userId", “user1")
                            .build()
                            .observe();
```

It sounds like you already have a `ServerList` implementation which is where you would do any event driven updates to your server list, but keep the load balancer the same.

Comment: Hi @hayduke.  After a few hours we also came up with that solution.  Thanks so much for confirming we were on the right track. :)